# What's the best way to send an input's data to a hidden input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, hidden-field

I have a form on a Website, and then another form inside of a Bootstrap modal.

The main form has certain fields e.g "Neck, Chest, Waist" while the form inside of the modal has only one e-mail field.

I'm planning to add some "hidden" inputs into the secondary form named "chest, waist" etc and I would like the main form field's value to be passed into the secondary form's hidden inputs as that's the one which is actually going to be submitted.

Is it possible without javascript? If not, I'd prefer some jQuery solution as it must be something pretty minor but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I've read some solutions like using the blur/keyup function etc but I just want to make sure that I'm using the best way to do this.

Comment: No it's not possible without using javascript. Use submit event of modal form to copy each field values to other form

Comment: @charlietfl okay so do you think this solution is better than using the "keyup/blur" function? I just want to make sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: I just thought that using "keyup" may not be the greatest of solutions.

Comment: Personally I would wait for user to complete all. The modal is likely obscuring the other form so using keyup would be overkill

Comment: That's exactly why I doubted about the "keyup" function. I guess I should go with your preferred solution then as it quite makes sure that the user has finalized all of their values and the fields that are being passed are the final results that appeared upon pressing the "submit" button of the secondary form.

Comment: Just make sure to prevent default submit of the modal form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the values of the form to the form with hidden `input`s when it is submitted. Copying on keyup is unnecessary.

```html
<form id="form1">
Input
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form id="form2">
<input type="text" id="input2"/>
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("input2").value = document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById("form2").submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: @charlietfl seems to have suggested a similar solution. But I kinda feel like going to another way around to how you suggested. Do you think if it would be more appropriate if I use the submit function of the 2nd form (the modal one) instead of the first form, how you're suggesting. Because right now I don't have any submit button for the first form. It only have that button to load the modal.

Comment: @user2971921 Just replace the submit button with the button to load the modal.

Comment: Okay, you really helped me, guys! I got it working :) Thank you so much.

Comment: @user2971921 No problem.